# hql equivalent query to this sql query

Tags: sql, hql

```
Select top 1 from <tablename>
```

what is hql query for the above ?

Answer (score 5):

Just write a normal query, ans use "**SetMaxResult**" to limit your results.

I.e.

```
return  getSession().createQuery("from items order by id asc")
            .setMaxResults(1)
            .list();
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you must use the `setMaxResults()` method.

See for example this question+answer : [How do you do a limit query in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use the setMaxResults of the [Query Object](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)).

To my knowledge, HQL does not support top or limit.