# HQL limit in subselect query

Tags: java, mysql, insert, hql

I want to insert foreign key of one table in another on basis of certain criteria. Structure is like

```
insert into CustomerResult(customer,draw) select c.idCustomer, from Customer c,Draw d where ..... and  c.idCustomer in (select cc.idCustomer from Customer cc where ..... limit 10)
```

here i want to insert only fix no of records which fulfill certain criteria. I know hql has no limit keyword but  want to implement like this. any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that what you want to do (use `limit` in subquery) is directly supported by Hibernate. Have a look at these previous answers:

- [How to set a limit to inner query in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738880/how-to-set-a-limit-to-inner-query-in-hibernate)
- [How do you do a limit query in HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)