# sql to hql throwing exception

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm using hibernate in my project and I'm trying to convert an existing sql query from DaoImplementation class to hql,

The sql query I have is

```
JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT site_id,rtc,sigplan,cycle_time,health,phase_no,phase_time,active_groups,groupscolour,ip "+
                 "FROM status_data where  rtc>='" + fromDate + "' and rtc<'" + toDate + "' and "+
                 "site_id=" + SiteId + " order by rtc desc limit "+recordLimit+" )as temp ORDER BY RTC ASC";
```

I wrote the hql version to get data from HealthLog table as

```
String hql = " select f from (select h from HealthLog h where rtc>='"+fromDate+"' and rtc <'"+toDate+"' "
            + "and siteId = "+siteId+" order by rtc desc limit "+limit+" ) as f order by rtc asc ";
    return super.readListByHql(hql);
```

But the above hql throws the following exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 16 [ select f from (select h from com.traff.hibernate.model.HealthLog as h where rtc>='1974-08-01 14:10:00.0' and rtc <'1974-09-01 23:46:20.6' and siteId = 20 order by rtc desc limit 50000 ) as f order by rtc asc ]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
at org.hibernate.hql.intern
```

I also tried the below code snippet but that giving me wrong results

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();     
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("rtc", fromDate));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("rtc", toDate));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("siteId", siteId));
    criteria.setMaxResults(limit);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("rtc"));            
    criteria2 = criteria;
    criteria2.addOrder(Order.desc("rtc"));      
    return criteria2.list();
```

Which is the correct way to achieve the result?

Comment: which version of hibernate?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto 4.1.9.Final

Comment: You can't use subqueries in the from clause in HQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269010/jpa-hibernate-subquery-in-from-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as already mentioned in the comments, you cannot do a subquery within the FROM clause in HQL.
See: [Hibernate Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-subqueries)

Secondly, the limit keyword is not supported by HQL.
Usually you would use `query.setFirstResult(0)` and `query.setMaxResults(recordLimit)` methods where query has the type of the Query Interface. But since you are using the limit in a subquery, there is no way.
See: [How to set a limit to inner query in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738880/how-to-set-a-limit-to-inner-query-in-hibernate)

Some options:

1. Use a native SQLQuery
2. Since you are only sorting in the outer Query. You could only execute the inner query and sort in Java.

Example for Option 2:

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Query query = session
    .createQuery("FROM HealthLog "
        + "WHERE rtc >= :rtcL and rtc < :rtcG and siteId = :siteId "
        + "ORDER BY rtc DESC");
query.setParameter("rtcL", fromDate);
query.setParameter("rtcG", toDate);
query.setParameter("siteId", siteId);
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(recordLimit);
List<HealthLog> res = query.list();
session.close();

Collections.sort(res, new Comparator<HealthLog>() {
  public int compare(HealthLog o1, HealthLog o2) {
    return o1.getRtc().compareTo(o2.getRtc());
  }
});
```

The query above returns HealthLogs with all attributes. If you want to only retrieve specific attributes, you can add a `SELECT new HealthLog(siteId,rtc,sigplan,cycle_time,...)` to your Query with a fitting constructor in `HealthLog`.

Please note that the code snippet might not be ready to use, since i do not know your model and attribute names.