# How to solve following issue in java?

Tags: java, hibernate

Im getting following error while running the query.

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'LIMIT' near line 1, column 194 [from com.claystone.db.Gpsdata where id.mobileunitid = '2090818044' and gpsdate in (select id.gpsdate from com.claystone.db.Gpsdata where id.mobileunitid = '2090818044' ORDER BY id.gpsdate DESC LIMIT 1 )  and gpsstatus='true']
```

This is my Query.Please give the suggession what is the mistake in this query?

```
data=session.createQuery[from com.claystone.db.Gpsdata where id.mobileunitid = '2090818044' and gpsdate in (select id.gpsdate from com.claystone.db.Gpsdata where id.mobileunitid = '2090818044' ORDER BY id.gpsdate DESC LIMIT 1 )  and gpsstatus='true']
```

Comment: I believe HQL does not support the LIMIT keyword. If you cannot rewrite the query you could use a native query... Not the most portable option. :(. I'm curious about other answers though.

Comment: @Bogdan - which leads to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why are you using the subquery? just do it like this :

```
data=session.createQuery[from com.claystone.db.Gpsdata where id.mobileunitid = '2090818044' and gpsstatus='true' ORDER BY id.gpsdate DESC LIMIT 1]
```

you might need to take the `LIMIT 1` off the end and use `.setMaxResults(1)` on the query.

Comment: I believe he wants to limit the subquery result to 1 not the whole result set :). I'd be interested too to know how is done in JPA

Comment: What about when you want to use a subquery select inside of your main select statement. It needs to return only 1 item.

Comment: but the subquery seems to join on the same table/object - so surely you can do it with just a single query/orderby/limit as i've suggested?

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand , If you use createQuery() instead of CreateSQLQuery() same error can be seen. "expecting CLOSE, found 'LIMIT'" or "expecting CLOSE, found 'NULL'