# How to convert SQL- Query with subselect into HQL Query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to convert following Query into HQL Query. How can i do?

`select * from gpsdata where mobileunitid = '2090818044' and gpsdate in (select gpsdate from gpsdata where mobileunitid = '2090818044' ORDER BY gpsdate DESC LIMIT 1 )  and gpsstatus='true'`

Comment: Seems like related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995427/how-to-solve-following-issue-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from GpsData " +
                              "where mobileUnitId = '2090818044' " +
                              "and gpsDate in " +
                              "(select gpsDate from GpsData " +
                              "where mobileUnitId = '2090818044' " +
                              "ORDER BY gpsDate DESC LIMIT 1) " +
                              "and gpsStatus='true'");
```

, should work.