# hibernate top N rows HQL query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, hql

I am using the following code to execute an HQL query with Hibernate:

```
String myHqlQuery = "select from MyTable where Something = ? order by SomeVal";
// Set bind values ...
getHibernateTemplate().find(myHqlQuery, bindParams);
```

Now, I want to select the top N rows from the table.  I know mySql has the LIMIT keyword which is not available in HQL.  I also know that Hibernate has the `setMaxResults()` method you can run on a `Query` object.

My question is - is there any way to add the "limit" constraint without have to change my code too much (i.e. executing the query via a HibernateTemplate object)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do a limit query in HQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

Comment: your right..thanks..this question can be closed then I guess..unless of course theres actually way to do this now directly with HQL.

Answer (score 3):

The below code works for me

```
    HibernateTemplate ht = getHibernateTemplate();
    ht.setMaxResults(10);
    List<Object> obj= ht.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("namedQuery",
            new String[] { "parameter1" },
            new Object[] { parameter1 });
```

So I think you should be able to do:

```
String myHqlQuery = "select from MyTable where Something = ? order by SomeVal";

// Set bind values ...

HibernateTemplate ht = getHibernateTemplate();

ht.setMaxResults(10);

ht.find(myHqlQuery, bindParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable

```
int numberOfItems = 10;

Pageable pageableTop = new PageRequest(0, numberOfItems);
yourRepository.findYourEntity(pageableTop);
```