# spring mvc hibernate performance issues

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

We are working on a spring mvc project with hibernate.

When we execute the following code:

```
try {
    HibernateTemplate ht = new HibernateTemplate(sf);
    List<Route> r = ht.findByNamedParam("select r from Route r inner join r.carPoolers as carPooler where (( r.owner.id  = :userid ) or ( carPooler.user.id = :userid )) AND r.id =:routeID", new String[]{"userid", "routeID"} , new Object[]{ u.getId() , id});
    if (r.size() == 1) {
        return r.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
} catch (DataAccessException ex) {
    LogFactory.getLog(RouteRepository.class).fatal(ex);
    return null;
}
```

this is the result:

```
SELECT ROUTE0_.ID AS ID4_, ROUTE0_.ARRIVALTIME AS ARRIVALT2_4_, 
    ROUTE0_.CAR_ID AS CAR13_4_, ROUTE0_.DATE AS DATE4_, 
    ROUTE0_.DAYOFWEEK AS DAYOFWEEK4_, ROUTE0_.DEPARTURETIME AS 
    DEPARTUR5_4_, ROUTE0_.ENDDATE AS ENDDATE4_, ROUTE0_.MESSAGEID 
    AS MESSAGEID4_, ROUTE0_.OPENSEATS AS OPENSEATS4_, 
    ROUTE0_.OWNER_ID AS OWNER14_4_, ROUTE0_.ROUTECACHE_ID AS 
    ROUTECACHE11_4_, ROUTE0_.ROUTEOPTIMIZED AS ROUTEOPT9_4_, 
    ROUTE0_.START_ID AS START12_4_, ROUTE0_.STOP_ID AS STOP10_4_ 
FROM ROUTE ROUTE0_ INNER JOIN CARPOOLER CARPOOLERS1_ ON 
    ROUTE0_.ID=CARPOOLERS1_.ROUTEID 
WHERE (route0_.owner_id=? or carpoolers1_.user_id=?) and route0_.id=?

    SELECT CAR0_.ID AS ID5_3_, CAR0_.BRAND_ID AS BRAND8_5_3_, CAR0_.CARNAME 
        AS CARNAME5_3_, CAR0_.CARTYPE AS CARTYPE5_3_, CAR0_.IMAGEURL AS 
        IMAGEURL5_3_, CAR0_.PRICEKM AS PRICEKM5_3_, CAR0_.SEATS AS 
        SEATS5_3_, CAR0_.USER_ID AS USER7_5_3_, BRAND1_.ID AS ID6_0_, 
        BRAND1_.BRANDNAME AS BRANDNAME6_0_, USER2_.ID AS ID0_1_, 
        USER2_.EMAIL AS EMAIL0_1_, USER2_.FACEBOOKID AS FACEBOOKID0_1_, 
        USER2_.FIRSTNAME AS FIRSTNAME0_1_, USER2_.GENDER AS GENDER0_1_, 
        USER2_.IMAGEURL AS IMAGEURL0_1_, USER2_.LANGUAGE_ID AS 
        LANGUAGE12_0_1_, USER2_.LASTNAME AS LASTNAME0_1_, 
        USER2_.MOBILEPHONE AS MOBILEPH8_0_1_, USER2_.PASSWORD AS 
        PASSWORD0_1_, USER2_.SMOKER AS SMOKER0_1_, USER2_.TELEPHONE AS 
        TELEPHONE0_1_, LANGUAGE3_.ID AS ID9_2_, LANGUAGE3_.LANGUAGE AS 
        LANGUAGE9_2_, LANGUAGE3_.LANGUAGECODE AS LANGUAGE3_9_2_ 
    FROM CAR CAR0_ LEFT OUTER JOIN BRAND BRAND1_ ON 
        CAR0_.BRAND_ID=BRAND1_.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN USER USER2_ ON 
        CAR0_.USER_ID=USER2_.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN LANGUAGE LANGUAGE3_ ON 
        USER2_.LANGUAGE_ID=LANGUAGE3_.ID 
    WHERE car0_.id=?

    SELECT USER0_.ID AS ID0_1_, USER0_.EMAIL AS EMAIL0_1_, 
        USER0_.FACEBOOKID AS FACEBOOKID0_1_, USER0_.FIRSTNAME AS 
        FIRSTNAME0_1_, USER0_.GENDER AS GENDER0_1_, USER0_.IMAGEURL AS 
        IMAGEURL0_1_, USER0_.LANGUAGE_ID AS LANGUAGE12_0_1_, 
        USER0_.LASTNAME AS LASTNAME0_1_, USER0_.MOBILEPHONE AS 
        MOBILEPH8_0_1_, USER0_.PASSWORD AS PASSWORD0_1_, USER0_.SMOKER 
        AS SMOKER0_1_, USER0_.TELEPHONE AS TELEPHONE0_1_, LANGUAGE1_.ID 
        AS ID9_0_, LANGUAGE1_.LANGUAGE AS LANGUAGE9_0_, 
        LANGUAGE1_.LANGUAGECODE AS LANGUAGE3_9_0_ 
    FROM USER USER0_ LEFT OUTER JOIN LANGUAGE LANGUAGE1_ ON 
        USER0_.LANGUAGE_ID=LANGUAGE1_.ID 
    WHERE user0_.id=?

    SELECT ROUTECACHE0_.ID AS ID7_2_, ROUTECACHE0_.AANTALM AS AANTALM7_2_, 
        ROUTECACHE0_.AANTALMIN AS AANTALMIN7_2_, ROUTECACHE0_.ACTIVE AS 
        ACTIVE7_2_, ROUTECACHE0_.JSON AS JSON7_2_, 
        ROUTECACHE0_.LOCATIONS AS LOCATIONS7_2_, 
        ROUTECACHE0_.LOCATIONSOPTIMIZED AS LOCATION7_7_2_, 
        ROUTECACHE0_.ROUTEOPTIMIZED AS ROUTEOPT8_7_2_, 
        ROUTECACHE0_.START_ID AS START10_7_2_, ROUTECACHE0_.STOP_ID AS 
        STOP9_7_2_, LOCATION1_.ID AS ID2_0_, LOCATION1_.LANG AS 
        LANG2_0_, LOCATION1_.LAT AS LAT2_0_, LOCATION1_.NUMBER AS 
        NUMBER2_0_, LOCATION1_.STREET AS STREET2_0_, LOCATION1_.ZIPCODE 
        AS ZIPCODE2_0_, LOCATION2_.ID AS ID2_1_, LOCATION2_.LANG AS 
        LANG2_1_, LOCATION2_.LAT AS LAT2_1_, LOCATION2_.NUMBER AS 
        NUMBER2_1_, LOCATION2_.STREET AS STREET2_1_, LOCATION2_.ZIPCODE 
        AS ZIPCODE2_1_ 
    FROM ROUTECACHE ROUTECACHE0_ LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION LOCATION1_ ON 
        ROUTECACHE0_.START_ID=LOCATION1_.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION 
        LOCATION2_ ON ROUTECACHE0_.STOP_ID=LOCATION2_.ID 
    WHERE routecache0_.id=?

     SELECT ROUTECACHE0_.ROUTECACHESPUNTENTUSSEN_ID AS ROUTECAC1_1_, 
        ROUTECACHE0_.ROUTECACHETUSSENPUNTEN_ID AS ROUTECAC2_1_, 
        LOCATION1_.ID AS ID2_0_, LOCATION1_.LANG AS LANG2_0_, 
        LOCATION1_.LAT AS LAT2_0_, LOCATION1_.NUMBER AS NUMBER2_0_, 
        LOCATION1_.STREET AS STREET2_0_, LOCATION1_.ZIPCODE AS 
        ZIPCODE2_0_ 
    FROM ROUTECACHE_LOCATION_PUNTEN ROUTECACHE0_ LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION 
        LOCATION1_ ON 
        ROUTECACHE0_.ROUTECACHETUSSENPUNTEN_ID=LOCATION1_.ID 
    WHERE routecache0_.routecachesPuntenTussen_id=?

     SELECT CARPOOLERS0_.ROUTEID AS ROUTEID5_, CARPOOLERS0_.ID AS ID5_, 
        CARPOOLERS0_.ID AS ID3_4_, CARPOOLERS0_.APPROVED AS 
        APPROVED3_4_, CARPOOLERS0_.ONETIME AS ONETIME3_4_, 
        CARPOOLERS0_.ROUTEID AS ROUTEID3_4_, CARPOOLERS0_.START_ID AS 
        START5_3_4_, CARPOOLERS0_.STOP_ID AS STOP7_3_4_, 
        CARPOOLERS0_.USER_ID AS USER6_3_4_, LOCATION1_.ID AS ID2_0_, 
        LOCATION1_.LANG AS LANG2_0_, LOCATION1_.LAT AS LAT2_0_, 
        LOCATION1_.NUMBER AS NUMBER2_0_, LOCATION1_.STREET AS 
        STREET2_0_, LOCATION1_.ZIPCODE AS ZIPCODE2_0_, LOCATION2_.ID AS 
        ID2_1_, LOCATION2_.LANG AS LANG2_1_, LOCATION2_.LAT AS LAT2_1_, 
        LOCATION2_.NUMBER AS NUMBER2_1_, LOCATION2_.STREET AS 
        STREET2_1_, LOCATION2_.ZIPCODE AS ZIPCODE2_1_, USER3_.ID AS 
        ID0_2_, USER3_.EMAIL AS EMAIL0_2_, USER3_.FACEBOOKID AS 
        FACEBOOKID0_2_, USER3_.FIRSTNAME AS FIRSTNAME0_2_, 
        USER3_.GENDER AS GENDER0_2_, USER3_.IMAGEURL AS IMAGEURL0_2_, 
        USER3_.LANGUAGE_ID AS LANGUAGE12_0_2_, USER3_.LASTNAME AS 
        LASTNAME0_2_, USER3_.MOBILEPHONE AS MOBILEPH8_0_2_, 
        USER3_.PASSWORD AS PASSWORD0_2_, USER3_.SMOKER AS SMOKER0_2_, 
        USER3_.TELEPHONE AS TELEPHONE0_2_, LANGUAGE4_.ID AS ID9_3_, 
        LANGUAGE4_.LANGUAGE AS LANGUAGE9_3_, LANGUAGE4_.LANGUAGECODE AS 
        LANGUAGE3_9_3_ 
    FROM CARPOOLER CARPOOLERS0_ LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION LOCATION1_ ON 
        CARPOOLERS0_.START_ID=LOCATION1_.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION 
        LOCATION2_ ON CARPOOLERS0_.STOP_ID=LOCATION2_.ID LEFT OUTER 
        JOIN USER USER3_ ON CARPOOLERS0_.USER_ID=USER3_.ID LEFT OUTER 
        JOIN LANGUAGE LANGUAGE4_ ON USER3_.LANGUAGE_ID=LANGUAGE4_.ID 
    WHERE carpoolers0_.RouteId=?
```

Problem:

- This takes minimum 460ms.
- We only need the first query for our results.

,
ty in advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably have so many queries because some relationships are eager loaded. Note that by default all OneToOne and ManyToOne relationships are eager loaded. This means that if a route has a car, which has a user, which has a language, etc., Hibernate will load all these referenced entities **each time** it loads a route.

Make them lazy loaded instead, and tune your queries to fetch only the entities you need.

Comment: We tried to lazy load everything which results in even more queries and the same response time :). thanks

Comment: does hibernate use the lazy settings in hql queries?

Comment: Yes, it does. If it still loads everything, then it means you have some code which traverses the relationships (maybe a toString call which would recursively call the owned entity's toString)

Comment: It does this in the repository itself. From the moment the list is initialized he does all those queries. Not in the code after.

Answer (score 0):

I guess returned object is passed to some automatic serializer (you use `@ResponseBody`, yes?) that tries to serialize the whole graph of accessible objects and therefore triggers lazy loading of related objects which you don't need.

If so, you can create a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that contains only necessary fields, populate it from the loaded entity and return that DTO instead of entity.

Alternative approach would be to configure serializer to make it serialize only necessary fields, but it can be more complex.

Comment: We don't use @ResponseBody. There is nothing serialized at the moment we get these queries. :)

Comment: @izar: How do you use result of `r.get(0);`?

Answer (score 0):

See this for how to get only 1 result: [How do you do a limit query in HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql).

Have you configured indexes on your tables?

Comment: Yes, we have indexed our tables :)