# Want to fetch only 5 records with HQL

Tags: hibernate, spring, hql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do a limit query in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

I am new to HQL. I have following working HQL query:

```
from Order as o where o.account.profile.userId='abc' order by o.orderID desc
```

This query returns me list of orders placed by user **abc** . User can have 0 to 5000+ orders placed in DB. But I want to display only **First 5** records(Orders). I am using sublist function of java List.

Can I directly fetch only first 5 records using HQL query? which is more efficient way to write this query?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can limit the results returned by a query by calling the `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` functions on the query object before running the query. Like so:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Order as o where o.account.profile.userId='abc' order by o.orderID desc");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(5); 
List result = query.list();
```

It depends on your DBMS used whether this will be handled in the DBMS directly.

Comment: I want to do this in hql. I don't know if it's possible or not in HQL

Answer (score 4):

Use `Criteria.setMaxResults(..)`:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Answer (score 3):

Directly from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-examples

```
Query q = s.createFilter( collection, "" ); // the trivial filter
q.setMaxResults(PAGE_SIZE);
q.setFirstResult(PAGE_SIZE * pageNumber);
List page = q.list();
```