# How to select last inserted 5 record from table using JPA with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

How to select last inserted 5 record from table using `JPA` with `Hibernate`?

```
public List<Sample> getAgencyChangeLastFiveRecords(){
    return (ArrayList<Sample>) createQuery(
        "select * from ( select * from sample order by id desc) where rownum<=5 order by rownum desc"
    );
}
```

This is not working. What would be the corresponding `HQL` query?

Comment: i don't know about hql but in sql i would use _order by rownum desc limit 5_

Comment: You can not do that with HQL you need to use Query, btw: possible duplicate of [How do you do a limit query in HQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you can try below

```
 String hql="from Sample order by id desc"
 Query.setMaxResults(5)
```