# How to limit a collection in an Object's property in hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two entities: item, and bid, each item have many bids for it, so bid is a collection property of item.

in the page that show an item, I just want to show the first 10 records of bids about this "item".

so, I do this query:

```
from item
left join fetch item.bids
where item.id=3
...
```

but this will fetch all bids about an item,
so, how to limit the bids about an item ?

Comment: if you have control over sql, you can use LIMIT and OFFSET commands

Comment: can we do this in a hibernate way?

Comment: You can use Limit. or else if you using Prepared Statement you can set max result limit

Answer (score 6):

This works so much better if you also have an association from Bid to Item.

Then you can select the items and apply the limit restriction:

```
session
    .createQuery(
    "select b
    from bid b
    join fetch b.item i
    where 
        i.id=3")
    .setMaxResult(10)
    .list();
```

Your previous query, the one selecting Item and fetching Bids will always select all items with all their bids and apply the max result limit in-memory. This is because Hibernate must always fetch all children, it can't give you partial collection results.

Selecting the child and joining the parent is a better alternative. The restriction applies to the selected children with no restriction whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

you can use criteria's setFirstResult() and setMaxResult(). or this post would be helpful for your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

example:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("your query here").setFirstResult(0).setMaxResult(10);
```

this will generate 10 rows of data from database

you have use annotation driven. simply add the annotation Size to your bid object

```
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "object", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Size(min=1, max=10)
    private Set<Bid>    bid;
```

Comment: this can limit the "item" not it's bids's record!

Comment: you can use annotation driven in your entity you could simply put @Size(min=1, max=10) to your one to many relationship or many to many

Comment: if we can override the mapping in a HQL way, it will be more flexible!

Comment: you can refer to this [link](http://www.journaldev.com/2954/hibernate-query-language-hql-example-tutorial) i guess

Answer (score 0):

For plain SQL, do the following:

```
Select B.*
From item I, bid B,
Where T.itemId = B.itemId
Limit 10;
```

Same can be done in case you are using hibernate, using criteria API or HQL
    HQL example:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from MyTable");
query.setMaxResults(10);

Criteria example: 
session.createCriteria(Abc.class)
                    .addOrder(Order.desc("id"))
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .list();
```

Comment: This only limit the "item" not the "bids" !