# Limit association size

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an article entity which contains list of comments. What I want is to get the article with comments ordered according to date in desc order and the top 5 comments. I know @OrderBy can be used to set order on association but how to limit the size of association fetched?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to limit the size of a @OneToMany collection with Hibernate or JPA Annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328187/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-size-of-a-onetomany-collection-with-hibernate-or-jp)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475975/jpql-hql-limit-items-for-list-of-children https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073122/how-to-limit-a-collection-in-an-objects-property-in-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You need a query, that returns comments.

```
select c from Article a 
join a.comments c 
where a.id = :articleId 
order by c.date desc
```

Then you can call [setMaxResults(5)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#setMaxResults-int-) on the query, and execute it.