# unexpected token: LIMIT error in hql

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
        List<AC_Customer> lastAC_CustomersList = session.createQuery("from AC_Customer order by customer_pk DESC LIMIT 1").list()
```

when i execute this i got this error can any one please tell me what is wron with my hql query.

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column 65 [from com.softlogic.models.AC_Customer order by customer_pk DESC LIMIT 1]

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239745/1932092

Comment: HQL is not SQL. It doesn't have any LIMIT clause. But you can set a max result on the Query itself.

Comment: thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

try using the below

```
session.createSQLQuery("select * from AC_Customer order by customer_pk DESC LIMIT 1").list();
```

Comment: He uses HQL, not SQL.

Answer (score 1):

`HQL` does not know `LIMIT` you have to use `setMaxResults` in a following way:

```
List<AC_Customer> lastAC_CustomersList = session
    .createQuery("from AC_Customer order by customer_pk DESC")
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .getResultList()
```

Answer (score 0):

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: OFFSET near line 1, column 87 [FROM om.omantel.prodsheet.models.RtcsProduct where status=1 order by TRACKING_ID DESC OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY]

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
     public List<RtcsProduct> pagination(int page_id, int total) {
    String listsql = "FROM RtcsProduct where status=1 order by TRACKING_ID DESC OFFSET "+page_id+" ROWS FETCH NEXT "+total+" ROWS ONLY";
    Session session = null;
    List<RtcsProduct> productlist = null;
    try {
    if (session == null) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        productlist = session.createQuery(listsql).list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return productlist;
}
```