# Hibernate: how to select all rows but the last N rows?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to run a `Hibernate` query that returns all the rows except the last 5 five rows, so my sql query is as follow:

```
session.createQuery("FROM Book 
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM Book ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5) 
ORDER BY title");
```

Unfortunately, the `LIMIT` not allowed in `Hibernate`, so I got an error saying:

> HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column 78 [FROM models.Book WHERE
>   id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM models.Book ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5) ORDER
>   BY title]

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer here

[How do you do a limit query in HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

> Limit was never a supported clause in HQL. You are meant to use setMaxResults().

Comment: I know that, but I can't use this method in my case, only if I looped the `LIMITED` results and then do the selection. I need something perform better :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are asking [hibernate pagination](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-pagination)

First get count:

```
String countQ = "Select count (f.id) from Foo f";
Query countQuery = session.createQuery(countQ);
Long countResults = (Long) countQuery.uniqueResult();
```

Then calculate your limit start and end points:

```
Long start = countResult - limit;
```

Then use pagination future:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Query query = sess.createQuery("From Foo");
query.setFirstResult(start );
query.setMaxResults(limit);
List<Foo> fooList = fooList = query.list();
```

You might have to update queries but I believe you get the idea

Comment: `setFirstResult` doesn't accept `Long`, only `'int`

Comment: And this method doesn't return the correct (ordered by id) order

Answer (score 0):

I have also asked similar kind of questions related to the limitation of "LIMIT" keyword in hibernate.

[Hibernate: how to select last N rows in ascending order of id? (in single query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099415/hibernate-how-to-select-last-n-rows-in-ascending-order-of-id-in-single-query/40101147#40101147)

I think there are only two ways left, though it is not the best performance.

1. Two queries (get the id list, then query with NOT IN id list)
2. One query with further data processing (eg. chop out last 5 data from a list of result)

hope it helps