# Hibernate Query Language typo?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I found this named query in an application I'm working on:

```
from UserBookmark as userBookmark where userBookmark.user.id = :userId order by userBookmark.id desc 5
```

The query is creating this error after upgrading to hibernate 5:

```
unexpected token: 5
```

Is there any legitimate reason for a '5' to be in the query or can I safely get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

I was googling the wrong thing. I found what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

This comment seems to be correct: (Referring to using this syntax to set max results)
"Hm... not too sure about this, [citation needed] this may be an accident and could suddenly stop working in a new version of hibernate."