# getsingle data restful WebAPI

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey

Below is my DAO class and resources class for get single data:

```
public List<Lipid> getLipid(int LipidId) {
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Lipid where LipidId = :LipidId");
    System.out.println("-----------123");
    List<Lipid> lipids = query.list();
    System.out.println("---------234");
    session.close();
    return lipids;
}
```

My Resources Class:

```
@GET
@Path("/{LipidId}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getLipid(@PathParam("param") int LipidId){
    LipidDAO dao = new LipidDAO();
    List lipid = dao.getLipid(LipidId);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(lipid);
    return Response.ok().entity(json.toString()).build();
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [LipidId] not set
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.verifyParametersBound(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:234)

Answer (score 0):

please set value of :LipidId
like this

```
query.setInteger("LipidId", LipidId);
```

Comment: Is It fine??  public List<Lipid> getLipid(int LipidId) {
        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Lipid where LipidId = :LipidId");
        System.out.println("-----------123");
        query.setInteger("LipidId", LipidId);
        List<Lipid> lipids = query.list();
        System.out.println("---------234");
        session.close();
        return lipids;
    }

Comment: sett the value for lipid id As show in above code. Now error is not coming bt still cannot getsingle data...   m having data with a particular id m passing then also getting [ ] in browser.. Help me Out??

Comment: please set limit  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql

Comment: Unknown parameter name : LipidId                                               
          public List<Lipid> getLipid(int LipidId) {
        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
       Query query = session.createQuery("from Lipid where LipidId = LipidId");
       query.setMaxResults(LipidId);
        query.setInteger("LipidId", LipidId);
        List<Lipid> lipids = query.list();
       tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return lipids;
    }

Comment: query.setMaxResults(1);

Comment: String json = new Gson().toJson(lipid.get(0));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146527/discussion-between-kamlesh-delat-and-mree).

Comment: Yes. I have set maxResult as 1.. Now also error is coming... Unknown parameter name : LipidId

Comment: change "from Lipid where LipidId = LipidId to "from Lipid where LipidId = :LipidId

Comment: Now Wat the error m getting is:                      
                  javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Answer (score 0):

Please set Query parameter in query.
post ur hibernateDao code here