# LIMIT breaking @Query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

so...

following loooong query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT A, B ... FROM ADMIN.SUPER_SEARCH WHERE A = :param OR B = :param ORDER BY A desc", nativeQuery = true )
```

will work just fine (i replaced few fields with ... it is a looong query)

but as soon as i add LIMIT 5 to end of query, it will throw

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

so this is the error query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT A, B ... FROM ADMIN.SUPER_SEARCH WHERE A = :param OR B = :param ORDER BY A desc LIMIT 5", nativeQuery = true )
```

*WHY?*

I would really need the limit here, since table is about 300k rows long..

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Comment: As an alternative, you can use setFirstResult (offset) and setMaxResults (limit) when creating the named query

Comment: Since you are using a native query, you must be sure 'LIMIT' is the proper oracle syntax to limit queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Comment: Please check below link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql

Comment: `LIMIT` is not valid for oracle

Comment: adding FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY; to end, didnt work either : (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT A, B ... FROM ADMIN.SUPER_SEARCH WHERE A = :param OR B = :param AND rownum <= 5 ORDER BY A desc", nativeQuery = true )
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider accepting the answer if it answered your question.