# expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I want to implement JPA query with INNER JOIN. I tried this:

```
@Override
    public Optional<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactionByWpfPaymentId(Integer id) {
        String hql = "SELECT t.* FROM " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " t " 
                + " INNER JOIN " + WpfPaymentPaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " wppt "
                + " ON t.id = wppt.payment_transaction_id " 
                + " WHERE wppt.wpf_payment_id = :id "
                + " ORDER BY t.id ASC LIMIT 1";
        TypedQuery<PaymentTransactions> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, PaymentTransactions.class).setParameter("id", id);
        List<PaymentTransactions> wpfPayments = query.getResultList();
        return wpfPayments.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(wpfPayments.get(0));
    }
```

But I get this error when I run the code:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1, column 10 [SELECT t.* FROM org.datalis.plugin.entity.PaymentTransactions t  INNER JOIN org.datalis.plugin.entity.WpfPaymentPaymentTransactions wppt  ON t.id = wppt.payment_transaction_id  WHERE wppt.wpf_payment_id = :id  ORDER BY t.id ASC LIMIT 1]
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue and what's causing it?

Probably I need to implement Spring Repository and make native query?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `t.*` with `t`.

You want `PaymentTransactions` object to be returned, not values of its fields.

Also HQL is not SQL, it doesn't support `*`.

Comment: How I get `message: "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column 227 [SELECT t FROM org.datalis.plugin.entity.PaymentTransactions t  INNER JOIN org.datalis.plugin.entity.WpfPaymentPaymentTransactions wppt  ON t.id = wppt.payment_transaction_id  WHERE wppt.wpf_payment_id = :id  ORDER BY t.id ASC LIMIT 1]"`

Comment: @PeterPenzov : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql