# Convert a SQL query to hql

Tags: sql, hql

I need to convert this query to hql to use it my code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    certificate_id , last_scan 
FROM 
    bcs_certificate_instance 
ORDER BY 
    last_scan 
LIMIT 5 ;
```

Who can help please?

Comment: It should work as it is in ```hql```. Have you tried just running it in ```hive```?

Comment: No it won't. There is not LIMIT keyword in hql.

Comment: Sorry, you're right I kind of assumed ```hql``` = ```hive querying language```. Which apparently is not the only way this acronym is used.

Comment: Check this out [How do you do a limit query in HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

Comment: I agreed with @OsamaKhalid Hibernate does not support the LIMIT keyword because that's only recognized by MySQL and PostgreSQL. For handling limit please use`setFirstResult`  `setMaxResults`

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct bci.certificate_id , bci.last_scan 
from bcs_certificate_instance bci
order by last_scan asc;
```

And for limit you have to use setMaxResults() funtion on query object before executing it.

A code snippet for this would look like:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(“select distinct bci.certificate_id , bci.last_scan 
from bcs_certificate_instance bci
order by last_scan asc;”);
query.setMaxResults(10);
List resultData = query.getResultList();
```

Thats it. So that is how you limit the number of records returned by a query in HQL.

Example with @Query annotation:

```
public interface PersonDao extends EntityDao<Person, Long> {

    @Query("select p from Person p where p.age between ?1 and ?2")

QueryResult<Person> findAllByAge(int minAge, int maxAge);

}
```

Once you have obtained a QueryResult, you can apply further options and restrictions to the query:

```
List<Person> result = personDao.findAllByAge(18, 65)

.sortAsc(Person_.lastName)

.sortDesc(Person_.age).

.firstResult(10)

.maxResults(10)

.getResultList();

}
```

Comment: I can't use the set max result option because i am using the @Query annotation .. so i have to set the max value in the query

Comment: I have added another example with @Query annotation. See if this is helpful to you. Thanks