# Database Select cost too high

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, inner-join

I want to use a double INNER SELECT on my database. If I use it via HIBERNATE and entities in my java application, the debugger gets an GC error.

```
  SELECT * FROM campaign WHERE id_campaign  IN 
    (SELECT id_campaign FROM event WHERE id_event IN 
     (SELECT id_event FROM dataset_event WHERE id_dataset=xxx)) limit 100;
```

Is there a better way with no GC error? Maybe a different select? Does Hibernate fills the event-entities of the second inner select? It is not necessary i guess..

FYI:

[image]

Error in console:

```
26-Feb-2020 09:36:36.575 SCHWERWIEGEND [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run Unexpected death of background thread [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Hibernate version is 5.3.3.final

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql

Comment: I use `query.setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList(); `later in my code.

Comment: `debugger gets an GC error` - Could you please provide the full error message? What hibernate version, database do you use?

Comment: edit my question :)

Comment: The OutOfMemoryError has nothing to do with the (very small) cost shown by the explain output. The database expects only 5 rows from that query, so it's really strange that you get an OOME - how many rows does the query really return? `explain (analyze)` would show that.

Comment: The execution plan is better shown as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). To do that, paste the plan as text into your question, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan to make sure you preserve the indention.

Comment: added analyzed query plan

Comment: The screen shot is hard to read ( formatted text would have been better). But as far as I can tell, the query returns **a single row**. Which means you most probably have several really gigantic columns (e.g. multiple JSON and text values) in that table. Otherwise the OOME can't be explained.

Comment: Hey, yeah it returns a single row. Maybe there is a problem with hibernate, cause if fills up the inner inner select in his entities ( like 288 entities to fill ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably does what you want:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM campaign c JOIN
     event e
     ON c.id_campaign = e.id_campaign JOIN
     dataset_event de
     ON de.id_event = e.id_event
WHERE de.id_dataset = xxx
LIMIT 100;
```

For performance, you want indexes on:

- `dataset_event(id_dataset, id_event)`
- `event(id_event, id_campaign)`
- `campaign(id_campaign)`

You may already have some or all of these.

The above might return duplicates.  Obviously, you could use `select distinct` or `distinct on`, but that could be quite expensive.  Instead, `exists` might be a better solution:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM campaign c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM event e JOIN
                   dataset_event de
                   ON de.id_event = e.id_event
              WHERE c.id_campaign = e.id_campaign AND
                    de.id_dataset = xxx
             )
LIMIT 100;
```

For this, you want indexes on:

- `event(id_campaign, id_event)`
- `dataset_event(id_event, id_dataset)`

Comment: are both solutions hibernate conform? I guess the real problem is, that my inner inner select returns 288 rows and hibernate wants to match them into the entities.

Comment: @Dennis . . . I don't know.  Both are compatible with Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I think to use this query is better than the above query:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM campaign  AS c
  OUTER APPLY(
     SELECT id_campaign FROM event AS e WHERE e.id_campaign = c.id_campaign
             ) AS p
  OUTER APPLY(
     SELECT id_event FROM dataset_event AS d WHERE id_dataset=xxx AND d.id_event = 
     p.id_event
             ) AS o
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "OUTER"
LINE 5:   OUTER APPLY(
          ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 54

Comment: `outer apply` is non-standard SQL. The equivalent standard SQL operator would be (I think) `left join lateral`

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 10:      p.id_event ) AS o