Spring repository query by property with limit/order by on child
I'm using Spring JPA/Hibernate and I'm trying to build custom query. Lets say we have Author and Book table. Author can have many books (he wrote them). Book has writtenAt (date) attribute.
Author class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}

Book class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "written_at", columnDefinition = "DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate writtenAt;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;
}

So first I want to order all children (books) of author by writtenAt attr and then select only latest by Top keyword.
Query to find all authors and their latest written book (writtenAt attr) - it's not working - syntaxt incorrect:
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {
     @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"books"})
     List<Author> findByOrderByBooks_writtenAtDescTop();
}

I'm really trying to make it work by this type of syntax query (not by @Query, getters, filters etc).
Thanks

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-jpql-or-hql - you have to write a custom query in some for or another.
